# Convert Date format while retaining datatype - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-formatting

Need to acquire YYYY-MM of **SYSDATE** and load to column (Data_Type = Date). The below query gives the required result, however, being convert to string datatype in the process.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL;
```

Any way to retain the Date datatype & acquire SYSDATE as YYYY-MM by purely using oracle

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @Rene Because, **Oracle does not store dates in the format you see. It stores it internally in 7 bytes with each byte storing different components of the datetime value.**

If you want to display, use TO_CHAR with proper FORMAT MODEL.

While inserting, use TO_DATE with proper FORMAT MODEL.

What you see as a format by default, is your locale specific NLS settings. I see your answer, and honestly, `SELECT to_date(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL` is just silly thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Dates don't have formats, so you can't set the format when it is saved. Formats only come into play when converting to or from a string.

If you want to save just the month year with day and time being 1 and midnight, `trunc(date_value, 'month')`. [Fomat models for round and trunc date.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084)

Comment: The first sentence is good. However, this - 

"*Formats only come into play when converting to of from a sting.*" is not completely true, as it is applicable vice-versa too. If you want to know why? Then the answer is **NLS dependency**. The best way to handle dates(if no time potion is involved) then use **ANSI Date literal** which uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. therefore it is **NLS independent**.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I think the "of" in "to of from a string" was a typo, and it should read "to or from a string", therefore Shannon has covered both directions of the conversion. I'd like to disagree with your opinion that the "best" way to handle dates is via the ANSI date literal; I personally find that it's much easier to read (and write) code using to_date when dealing with strings-that-are-really-dates, especially because you don't have to worry about changing approach for whether the date has a time or not. But clearly YMMV on that point! *{:-)

Comment: @Boneist "*I personally find that it's much easier to read (and write) code using to_date when dealing with strings-that-are-really-dates*" Even I found it easier, until I found that **ANSI date literal** is really a boon when I had to code for my `French, Russian, Egyptian.. etc.` clients who didn't care about the **time element** :-) Therefore, I don't have to mention `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` every time I code for these clients.

Comment: @LalitKumarB `to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` vs `DATE '2015-01-01'`; I still much prefer the to_date() expression, since it has the format right there! And it's still NLS independent! (I can never remember the correct format for the ANSI date literal...). But it's a case of semantics and whatever works best for you, IMHO.

Comment: @Boneist Well, I was exactly like you, but now almost after spending a good time using the ANSI date literal fixed format(seldom of course), I remember the format. It took some effort to convince [**Ed Stevens**](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/#comment-4031) too ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Convert it back to a date.

```
SELECT to_date(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL
```

Of course, to be a valid date there must be a day component. This will be set to 1.

Alternatively, why not just store the sysdate? Next time you look at that value you will only be interested in the year and month.

Comment: `SELECT to_date(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL` Why? It could be simply done using `TRUNC`. By the way, **as a matter of fact, formatting a date has nothing to do with storing it**.

Comment: Also, just to make it clear. I haven't down voted. I agree with your first statement, "*Convert it back to a date"*. But, as I said, there is no need for that. What's the need to convert the date into string, and then, again convert it back to date. That's way too complicated!

Comment: I thought I made that clear with my final remark.